# Adding a transition to a card

Tags: html, css

```css
.grid_content {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  colour: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

h4 {
  font-family: var(--font-style-custom);
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
}

h4,
p {
  position: relative;
  top: 85px;
}

.caption:hover {
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1), hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.6));
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_content">
  <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-psd/box-packaging-mockup-isolated_23-2149208917.jpg?w=740&t=st=1663223199~exp=1663223799~hmac=6f0288bfcdf858b4908269c5406636c1f3c0bfca3e70041f67d9adc5b0be7dea" alt="Brading image">
  <div class="caption">
    <h4>Laynard</h4>
    <p>Brand-identity</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I hover on the image, I want the background color to slowly transition in and out, but here it only transitions in and disappears when I don't hover, I've added transition to the caption div element in the card and it still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As initially the opacity of the element with the class `caption`'s opacity is set to `0`, it's recommended to include the `background` property in `.caption {...}` rather than in `.caption:hover {...}`.

Additionally, remove the `transition` property in `.caption:hover` as it's useless.

The issue with your implementation is that when the cursor hovers over the element, the background property is set, and when the cursor is not longer hovering over the element, the background property is *reset* and the `transiton` property doesn't get applied to it.

```css
.grid_content {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  colour: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1), hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.6));
}

h4 {
  font-family: var(--font-style-custom);
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
}

h4,
p {
  position: relative;
  top: 85px;
}

.caption:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_content">
  <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-psd/box-packaging-mockup-isolated_23-2149208917.jpg?w=740&t=st=1663223199~exp=1663223799~hmac=6f0288bfcdf858b4908269c5406636c1f3c0bfca3e70041f67d9adc5b0be7dea" alt="Brading image">
  <div class="caption">
    <h4>Laynard</h4>
    <p>Brand-identity</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your background style from `.caption:hover` to `.caption` 
You already made the transition of opacity

```css
.grid_content {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  colour: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1), hsl(0 0% 0% / 0.6));
}

h4 {
  font-family: var(--font-style-custom);
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
}

h4,
p {
  position: relative;
  top: 85px;
}

.caption:hover {
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_content">
  <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-psd/box-packaging-mockup-isolated_23-2149208917.jpg?w=740&t=st=1663223199~exp=1663223799~hmac=6f0288bfcdf858b4908269c5406636c1f3c0bfca3e70041f67d9adc5b0be7dea" alt="Brading image">
  <div class="caption">
    <h4>Laynard</h4>
    <p>Brand-identity</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is your answer different from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73726770/17235431) that was posted before than you?

Comment: when I started writing the answer, there were no answers at all